# How to increase LinkedBlockingQueue capacity?

Tags: java, data-structures, java-8

I want to increase LinkedBlockingQueue capacity?

By design it's unbounded(Integer.MAX_VALUE). We can limit by giving capacity as initial value. But I want to increase that capacity after creation. By the way It can contain items in that time.

How to achieve that , any ideas ?

Comment: Most likely you'll have to create a new `LinkedBlockingQueue` and transfer the elements over. This will have to be properly synchronized.

Comment: Why? Please explain why you think you need this.

Comment: @user207421 I will process concurrently this queue. And another thread increase this queue size if more capacity needed.

Comment: What are the conditions for resizing? If you resize simply because the `LinkedBlockingQueue` is full then why not just use an unbounded queue?

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html#%3Cinit%3E(int)) of the constructor that accepts a capacity states the following:

> Creates a LinkedBlockingQueue with the given (fixed) capacity.

The term *fixed* implies that the capacity cannot be modified after the queue has been created.

This is evident by the capacity being declared `final`:

```
/** The capacity bound, or Integer.MAX_VALUE if none */
private final int capacity;
```

If you want to increase the capacity of a fixed-size queue, you'll just need to create a new queue, or specify an initial capacity large enough to accommodate your needs.